# Put node app online privately so my team can preview it before launch?

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, security, vpn, digital-ocean

I'm building a Node app and need to put it online so my team can access it. We are concerned about the content of the app leaking and need some security.

Is a VPN the best way? Could I set one up easily on Digital Ocean or elsewhere? I have only set up a VPN for tunnelling before, and don't have a local computer or server that is always on.

I first thought about putting it on a randomly generated subdomain on my regular domain, or controlling it with .htaccess and password, but I'm not sure if this is doable with Node.

EDIT: what about just setting up with pptp and then editing the hosts file to point my-temporary-domain.com to localhost?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is relevant because you don't have a local area network that your team all has access to. The way I've solved this in the past is to set up your application listening on the `127.0.0.1` on a server that is accessible to the internet. Allow your team to have SSH access, and set it up so they forward `localhost` and port 80 on their local machine to whatever port your application is listening on. You can do this with `openssh` and `putty`.

Comment: Wouldn't that direct all their localhost traffic to my VPS, and how would it prevent anyone accessing the app just using the VPS IP address and port?